# Testing Auth0 locally on a serverless application using AWS Lambda Functions

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, auth0

Before my question, it's important to note that the app I'm working with has been given to me pre-built with little documentation. Long story. I've never worked with a serverless application before, hence my complete confusion.

Here's some context:

I have a serverless application: React app that sits in a S3 bucket, being served by AWS CloudFront. It uses Auth0 for authentication. Currently, the logic is, if a user tries to visit the app's domain, Auth0 pops-up with a login prompt. The user enters their credentials which is then sent to an AWS Lambda function, which exchanges the confirmed login credentials for a JSON web token. This is sent back to Auth0 which then redirects the user to the app's domain (Please critique this explanation if you think I've misexplained something).
I'm trying to test Auth0 locally so that I can access the roles I've assigned to each user to eventually serve that user data specific to their role.

Problem:

However, I'm unable to test Auth locally. When I run npm start at localhost:3000, I'm taken straight to the main page, skipping login entirely.

I understand this could be because of numerous things, but here's what I've tried.

I've gone to my Auth0 dashboard, and under Allowed Callback URLS, i put http://localhost:3000/logincb. (logincb is the callback given during the AWS Lambda step).

I tried using ngrok to create a secure connection and then putting this url in Allowed Callback URLs, still no Auth0 pop-up on localhost.

I tried putting in conditons in the Lambda function if the request url is localhost:3000 i.e do the exact same thing as you would if the request url was the app's domain name

I can post the Lambda function if that's helpful. It's similar to the examples given on AWS Lambda's docs for example functions when using Amazon CloudFront. It has functions for handling cookies, webtokens, post request to Auth0, etc.

I apologize for the vagueness of the question, I just need some inspiration/ideas at this point.

Peace and love

Comment: It seems likely that there is some code on the React side to help with this as S3 can't do this.

Comment: S3 can't do what?

Comment: A hosted server (i.e. Apache, Nginx, etc.) can look at a URL and know that it requires some sort of authorization.  S3 cannot.  So the "if a user tries to visit the app's domain, Auth0 pops-up with a login prompt" must be done inside of the React code.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: I understand! I guess I hesitated writing code on the front-end because I thought maybe the fact that the app is serverless, authorization is handled differently, even in testing. I also thought that surely there would be reference to Auth somewhere in the React code, even commented out, just to confirm, OK, we tested Auth locally, here's the code we used for it. Thanks for your help, I'll let you know how I get on